# Powershell not reading spaces correctly

Tags: powershell, spacing

Simple issue, I'm trying to run the following command:

```
$d = ((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)).ToString('MMM')
$filepath = "<<PATH>>\EOM " + $d + " " + $d.Year
New-Item $filepath -type directory
```

Path works correctly, that is a parameter set by an external program.

I can't get it to recognise the " " + $d.Year in the path, it just stops after $d. Is there an easy way I can get it to read the whole file path? At the moment It keeps creating a new folder ...\EOM Sep without the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Year property of `$d` as you explicitly cast it to a string with `ToString('MMM')` Also instead of trying to concatenate spaces use a [string format](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/03/12/use-powershell-to-format-strings-with-composite-formatting/):

```
$d = ((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1))
$filepath = "<<PATH>>\EOM {0} {1}" -f $d.ToString('MMM'),$d.Year
New-Item $filepath -type Directory
```